# get profile information from facebook in android app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate facebook sdk with my android application and want to retrieve username,email and profile pic of the person logged in but I am getting a System error. My code is as follow-

```
package com.example.facebooklogin;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{




    // Your Facebook APP ID
        private static String APP_ID = "801614236517742"; // Replace your App ID here
        //private static String APP_ID = "308180782571605"; // Replace your App ID here

        // Instance of Facebook Class
        private Facebook facebook;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
        String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
        private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

        Button btn;

         String name;
         String email;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
            mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFbLogin);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            loginToFacebook();
            //getProfileInformation();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void loginToFacebook()
        {
            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

            if (access_token != null) 
            {



                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            }

            if (expires != 0)
            {
                facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }

            if (!facebook.isSessionValid())
            {
                facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                new DialogListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel()
                    {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values)
                    {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                        facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                        facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error)
                    {
                        // Function to handle error
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror)
                    {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
            }
            else
                getProfileInformation();
        }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void getProfileInformation() 
    {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                    // getting name of the user

                    name = profile.getString("name");
                    // getting email of the user
                    email = profile.getString("email");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Logcat of my app-

```
05-22 06:55:53.774: W/dalvikvm(3713): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
05-22 06:55:53.774: W/dalvikvm(3713): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
05-22 06:55:53.784: I/dalvikvm(3713): Could not find method android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance, referenced from method com.facebook.Session.postActiveSessionAction
05-22 06:55:53.784: W/dalvikvm(3713): VFY: unable to resolve static method 216: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;.getInstance (Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
05-22 06:55:53.784: D/dalvikvm(3713): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0009
05-22 06:55:54.514: D/dalvikvm(3713): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 224K, 9% free 3058K/3360K, paused 54ms, total 57ms
05-22 06:55:54.604: D/Facebook-Util(3713): GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAAEhug8jDagBAP7mXTSAg9pqFittCCALpgdciZCzhWya9pqRH0sB5puv36fD5bta2dNGTKHctWvaoaIBbCIDKLZACX3fNVFAv75u0YOULJZC7MLEZBiEpSOmUADEmB51gllXRTEAi5ZCLAfJGXuKOJIl9ZBJLqiWZAK51nHs5prITm5HrFOUr64D6f2M26ZAxZAk0Y2l5AZATZCznmzCGSDksXQ&format=json
05-22 06:55:57.034: D/Profile(3713): {"error":{"message":"Error validating application. Application has been deleted.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}
05-22 06:55:57.044: W/System.err(3713): org.json.JSONException: No value for name
05-22 06:55:57.044: W/System.err(3713):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
05-22 06:55:57.044: W/System.err(3713):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:515)
05-22 06:55:57.044: W/System.err(3713):     at com.example.facebooklogin.MainActivity$2.onComplete(MainActivity.java:145)
05-22 06:55:57.084: W/System.err(3713):     at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:276)
```

Comment: have you created HashKey for your facebook app?

Comment: facebook have did some changes in its development console, so I think you have forgot something there.

Comment: @pratik- Of course...this is obvious.

Comment: jus a min I have suffered with this problem before, let me give you clarification about that okay.

Comment: have you verified your email id in developer console?

Comment: @pratik-How to verify email id in developer console?

Comment: we must need to verify all the settings anushka, can v go to chatroom here? it will b easy I think

Comment: @pratik-thanku very much 4 ur help...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54195/discussion-between-pratik-and-anushka-agarwal).